# Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement" because this.driver is null with the implementation of testContextSetup.driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, frameworks, cucumber, bdd

I am getting this error when executing my code in my Cucumber Framework:

```
FAILED: runScenario("Search Experience for product search in both home and Offers page", "Search and Place the order for Products")
        Runs Cucumber Scenarios
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By)" because "this.driver" is null
at pageObjects.OffersPage.searchItem(OffersPage.java:21)
at stepDefinitions.OfferPageStepDefinition.user_searched_for_same_shortname_in_offers_page(OfferPageStepDefinition.java:40)
```

Following is my code in OffersPage class where it's referring :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class OffersPage {
    
public WebDriver driver;
    
    public OffersPage(WebDriver driver)
    {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
    
    By search = By.xpath("//input[@type='search']");
    By productName = By.cssSelector("tr td:nth-child(1)"); //This is the product name
    
    public void searchItem(String name)

    {
        driver.findElement(search).sendKeys(name);
    }
    
    
    public void getSearchText()
    {
        driver.findElement(search).getText();
    }
    
    public String getProductName() //Here we are returning the Product name
    {
        return driver.findElement(productName).getText();
    }
}
```

This is my OffersPage StepDefinition File code (line 40) as pointed in the error message:

```
    @Then("user searched for {string} shortname in offers page")
    public void user_searched_for_same_shortname_in_offers_page(String shortName) throws InterruptedException {
      // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    
    switchToOffersPage();
    OffersPage offersPage = new OffersPage(testContextSetup.driver);// the driver here will be linked to the OffersPage page object class
    offersPage.searchItem(shortName);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    offerPageProductName = offersPage.getProductName();
```

Where am I going wrong exactly?

Comment: Update the question with the implementation of `testContextSetup.driver`

Comment: Yes just done that now

Comment: But what is _`testContextSetup`_?

Comment: As requested please provide the ```testContextSetup``` method